# When I print my objects, the species of the object shows up as null instead of saying the species (example it should say balrog)

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I need to have the name, species name, hitpoints, and strength appear. Everything prints except for the species name which prints as null. Any ideas why?

this is in my main class

```
if (species.equals("b") || species.equals("B")) {
    Creature balrog = new Creature(name, strength, hit);
    players.add(balrog);
    System.out.println("Current Players: ");
    System.out.println("NAME | SPECIES | STRENGTH | HIT POINTS");
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(players.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

this is in my Creature class which is what will print everything

```
public String toString() {
    String result = name;
    result += " | ";
    result += species;
    result += " | ";
    result += strength;
    result += " | ";
    result += hitPoints;
    result += "\n";
    return result;
}
```

Then finally, the Balrog class, a subclass of creature

```
Balrog(String name, int strength, int hit){
    super(name,strength,hit);
}//ends Balrog constructor

String getSpecies(){
    return "Balrog";
}
```

There are no error messages, It just prints out null where the species name should be.

Comment: Are you specifically referring to this?:  `result += species;`  Where do you assign a value to that variable?  Or even declare that variable?  This example looks incomplete.

Comment: In your example you are never setting the species.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an instance of the super class instead of the sub class

```
Creature balrog = new Creature(name, strength, hit);
```

should be

```
Creature balrog = new Balrog(name, strength, hit);
```

You'll also need to get the sub class' species in the toString

```
public String toString() {
    String result = name;
    result += " | ";
    result += getSpecies();
    result += " | ";
    result += strength;
    result += " | ";
    result += hitPoints;
    result += "\n";
    return result;
```

Comment: Your Creature class should be `abstract` and the `getSpecies()` method should be abstract.